# mysql_query with PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql

This should be easy but I'm can't make it work.
The idea is to look for an email adress posted from a form. If it exists echo something and if not echo something else.

My code is:

```
<?php
//MySQL Database Connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "********", "**********") 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//get data from form 
$email=$_POST['email'];

//ask the database for coincidences
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pressmails WHERE email='.$email.'"); 
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result); 


 if($num_rows < 0){ 
    echo "The user is registered";
} else { 
    echo "The user is not registered";
}  

 //Close database connection
 mysql_close();
 ?>
```

Comment: The `mysql`-extension is outdated. Read more http://php.net/en/mysql-connect. // Oh, and you are obviously introduce some SQL-injections

Comment: Do not use `mysql_*`. They are deprecated now, and you should get into the habit of using `mysqli` as a minimum...

Comment: are you getting the message that the user is not registered? i think perhaps your `$num_rows<0` is the wrong way round...

Comment: @BenM You slightly scared me when you mentioned `mysqli` until I read "as a minimum" ;)

Comment: Thank you all. I have just changed. It was not the problem, though...

Comment: `mysql_close` is only usefull when you use `mysql_pconnect` to connect to a database.

Comment: @PedrodelSol it does not even get any value at $num_rows. It is an empty variable always. The error is    Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebPremsa\Validation.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\WebPremsa\Validation.php on line 11
The user is not registered

Comment: are you now using `mysqli_*`?

Comment: @Jaume - The syntax for `mysqli` and `mysql` functions are very similar, but they are not identical; if you're taking our advice and switching to `mysqli`, you should read the manual to see how they differ. HINT: `mysqli` functions require the connection variable, as returned from `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: @PedrodelSol it does not work either with mysql or mysqli. The variable $num_rows is empty always.

Answer (score 3):

You are not concatenating string properly.

`$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pressmails WHERE email='.$email.'");`

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pressmails WHERE email='".$email."'");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should end the string by using a closing quote (if you started the string with `"` you must end the string with `"` too, same for `'`).

And do not forget to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string), otherwise the script is not safe.

The script will become something like this:

```
// save the query in a variable, so we can echo it to debug when it doesn't work as expected
$sql = "SELECT email FROM pressmails WHERE email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried and it does not work, but if I echo $sql prints the string OK. When I echo $result it prints nothing. I have checked the query at phpmyadmin and it works... THIS IS VERY WEIRD, right???

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the concatenation identifiers, since wrapping a literal in `"` will automatically parse variables into the string:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM pressmails WHERE email='$email'");
```

You should watch out, mind you. Doing the above represents a significant SQL injection vulnerability. You should consider sanitizing `$email` as a minimum. Also see my comment about the `mysql_*` functions in PHP.

From the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php):

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_close() PDO: Assign the value of NULL to the PDO object

Comment: Thanks for all your help but it still does not work regardless if I use mysql or mysqli. The variable $num_rows is empty when I enter a registered email or an unregistered one... Any idea??? Thanks!!!

Comment: `$num_rows` will never be less than 0. It will either be 0, or greater. You need to check for `if($num_rows > 0)`...

Answer (score 0):

(assuming you get your syntax errors corrected) isn't the logic of this backwards?

```
if($num_rows < 0){ 
 echo "The user is registered";
} else { 
echo "The user is not registered";
}
```

if the user is registered their email is in the database and the query returns one or more rows

try

```
if($num_rows){ 
   echo "The user is registered";
} else { 
  echo "The user is not registered";
}
```

Comment: better is to use `$num_rows > 0`, apart from that the complete query check is missing and this should be a comment, not an answer.